# Error whent trying to deploy shiny app: multiple existing deployments from this application directory already exist

Tags: r, shiny

When trying to deploy my shiny app

```
shinyapps::deployApp('C:\\MyProgramProject\\MyApp')
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to deploy using default arguments (multiple existing deployments from this application directory already exist). Please specify appName and/or account name explicitly.

I have a similar app under an entirely separate directory with a different shiny account which was uploaded from the separate directory.  I made sure that I entered the correct token for the account and I can see in the shiny server of the account I want to upload to that there are no applications there at all. I also copied the ui.R and server.R files to a new subdirectory called `Deploy`and tried to upload from there with identical results.  Again, the tokens and directory paths are correct.

The reason we want to deploy to the new account is because we have had a lot of traffic and want to set up a new paid account with a higher allowance but need to make sure it works first.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my three-year old spelling.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing any directory called  `rsconnect` or `shinyapps` from your application folder.

You can also try calling:

`deployApp(appName="my-app-name", account="my-account-name")`

Comment: What finally worked was clicking the republish button several times.